# Javascript,doesn't show undefined number

Tags: javascript

I've created a variable with keys and values which looks like:

```
var e = new Array();
e[0] = "Bitte";
e[1] = "Danke";
```

Besides this I added a line in the variable which shows a text when the number is undefined.

```
e[NaN] = "Change Settings";
```

So when the variable `e` is `NaN` ("undefined"), I want that he doesn't displays the Number of the variable e in the input. I tried to achieve this as you can see, but it won't function.

```
if (neuezahl = NaN) {
  document.getElementById("saveServer").value="";
} else {
  document.getElementById("saveServer").value=""+neuezahl+""; 
}
```

Comment: change (neuezahl = NaN) into (neuezahl == NaN)

Comment: why not use directly if(typeof neuezahl !== "undefined"){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` can't be compared directly (it's not even equal to itself `NaN === NaN ==> false`). Use `isNaN()` to detect `NaN`:

```
if (isNaN(neuezahl)) {...}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have assigned `neuzahl` not compared it, aside that use the `isNAN` function:

```
if (isNAN(neuezahl))
{
   document.getElementById("saveServer").value="";
}
else 
{
   document.getElementById("saveServer").value=""+neuezahl+""; 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 0):

the condition in the if statement may not correct. Now you use "=" not "==", it is an assignment statement and the condition will always true. So if you want to check "neuezahl" is "NaN", function isNaN may help.

```
if (isNaN(neuezahl)){...}
else {}
```

Comment: Actually `(a = NaN) ==> NaN`, hence condition is always falsy. (Assigning value in a condition throws a syntax error in strict mode.)